# What happens with error responses when using fetch with next/revalidate option enabled?

Tags: next.js, fetch-api

An application I'm currently working on was built on top of the Next.js framework. I'm migrating a few API routes from the Page router to the more recent App router.

Some of these routes make requests to external APIs. I have worked with the App router before, but this question came to mind only now, mainly because one of these third-party APIs is really unstable: what happens with error responses when using fetch with next/revalidate option enabled? Example from the [Next.js docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/fetching-caching-and-revalidating#time-based-revalidation):

```
fetch('https://...', { next: { revalidate: 3600 } })
```

I have a guess, but I wanted to confirm since I couldn't find an answer in the official docs: Is the response not cached if its status is something above 300 (redirect, client, or server errors)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If an error is thrown during revalidation, Nex.js uses the latest successful cache as they say on the [doc](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/fetching-caching-and-revalidating#error-handling-and-revalidation):

> If an error is thrown while attempting to revalidate data, the last successfully generated data will continue to be served from the cache. On the next subsequent request, Next.js will retry revalidating the data.